# How to get Information Entropy and Chi-Square Test value for an encrypted image

Tags: entropy, image-processing, chi-squared

I was reading [this](https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/18/8/276/htm) paper. Under the section `4.3` and  `4.5` they add **The Chi-Square Test Analysis of Cipher Image** and **Information Entropy Analysis** respectively. I was interested to know how they manage to get the `p-value` and calculate Entropy from an encrypted image (theoretical perspective).

Any idea or suggestion or provide a script will be appreciated. Or redirect me to any blog/article where those analyses were discussed in details will be appreciated to. I googled them but didn't get enough information to implement or write a python script to test for an encrypted image.

I was wondering how to test/identify that an encrypted image is good one or hard to decrypt. Is there any theory based on this topic?

Comment: They're obtaining the relative frequencies of byte-values occurring in the binary file of the image, and doing a [chi-square goodness-of-fit test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Discrete_uniform_distribution) for a uniform distribution on 0,1,...,255. Similarly, they compute the entropy -- using these frequencies to estimate the probabilities in the formula they give -- to see how it compares to the entropy of the uniform distribution. Since there are $2^8$ possible byte values, a uniform distribution will have entropy $\log_2(2^8)=8$ (bits).

Comment: The idea is that good encryption produces a file indistinguishable from uniformly random bits/bytes.

Comment: You may want to read https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/57936 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/59589041/1033647